# Is there a way to deal with greek characters in python?

Tags: python, pdftotext

Is there a way i can get this code working in python?

```
import os
import subprocess

path = "/home/workspace/test/2014"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    //print(file)
    subprocess.call(["pdftotext %s" % file])
```

I have a path where i store all my pdf files. Every file name has greek characters for example (ΤΕΣΤ_1_2014). When i run the above code i get an error like this

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's the difference between encode and decode for string? I have used both in the last line when i am creatin the txt file but none of them works
Please help!

Comment: A full traceback and real code would be nice. Also, Python version?

Comment: Does `subprocess.call([u"pdftotext",  u"%s" % file])` work?

Comment: I am using python 3.4
Well this is all the code. I made a small script so as to convert about 250 pdf files to txt files in order to analyse the text.
I don't know if subprocess works because the error has to do with the greek characters in the pdf files. 
Tell me what else would it be helpful so that i could post it.

Comment: Remove `print(file)`, use: `if file.endswith('.pdf'): subprocess.check_call(["pdftotext", file])`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks! Besides the fact that i had written [subprocess] wrong i had to decode the greek characters to utf-8. The best solution indeed is to rename the files without as all of them refer to the same name so everything is ok now.